# How can I raise an Exception if more than three arguments are passed into a function, function is called with *args, **kwargs?

Tags: python, exception, arguments, keyword-argument

So I have the following function:

```
def run_task(*args, **kwargs):
    jobserve_task_name = args[0]
    parser_code, group_name, real_execution_intdate = _extract_celery_task_args(*args, **kwargs)
```

And I want to raise an exception just above the last line, where if the total number of `*args, **kwargs` is greater than 3.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
if len(args) + len(kwargs) > 3:
    raise TypeError("too many arguments")
```

I used `TypeError` since that's the same exception you get if you pass too many arguments to a function with fixed arguments.

Comment: Hi @Tom Karzes, quick question, if I want to raise the error ONLY when more than 3 position arguments are passed is that possible? 
When I change the above to just `if len(args)) > 3:`, and I pass 3 positional arguments and 1 keyword argument, the error is still raised, but I don't want this, I only want to raise the error when strictly more than 3 positional arguments are passed.

Comment: @jikf The change you suggest should work.  If it doesn't, try printing both `args` and `kwargs` and see how the arguments are being packaged. It's probably not doing what you expect.

Comment: thank you, printing or logging is a good sugegsiton

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you.

```
if len(args) + len(kwargs) > 3:
    raise RuntimeError('Error message')
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know I could treat `args` and `kwargs` like that.

Answer (score 0):

Expounding on the other answer: `args` is literally a tuple, `kwargs` is literally a dictionary. `len` isn't the only thing you can with them.

```py
def foo(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    print(kwargs)
    
foo(1, 'a', True, hello='world', sun='shines')
```

Result:

```
(1, 'a', True)
{'hello': 'world', 'sun': 'shines'}
```